# Active Record includes with a belongs_to and has_many doesn't return associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invitations
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invitations
end
```

**invitation.rb**

```
class Invitation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :organization
end
```

I'm trying to query Active Record in the following way:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
user.invitations.includes(:organization)
```

I want to be able to get all invitations for the user and also have the invitations include attributes of their related organization. However, I am only getting the invitation and none of the organization's attributes.

Even if I try:

```
Invitation.includes(:organization)
```

I'm still not getting each invitation's associated organization.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any records when calling `Invitation.joins(:organization)` ?

Answer (score 0):

[includes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) method provides eager loading. This solves the N + 1 queries problem. You can access the loaded organization like `user.invitations.first.organization`. There will be no new queries here.

If you want to combine invitation and organization attributes, you can use joins and select.

```
user.invitations
    .joins(:organization)
    .select('invitations.*, organizations.foo, organizations.boo as blabla')
```

Answer (score 0):

@demir has already answered your question.

Just as an addition - probably, you mixed up `includes` for models with `include` option of `to_json` \ `as_json`.

If you want to return some JSON result (e.g. in your API response), then you can do `user.as_json(include: [invitations: { include: :organization }])`